# Xcode SwiftGen: build fails in project with multiple targets

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

How should I configure SwiftGen when using Cocoapods and multiple targets?

I have a project with two targets (MyProject and MyProject Dev) which has SwiftGen integrated with Cocoapods.

I can build the first target with no problems whatsoever. However the 'Dev' target always fails. The script phase is the last step in Build Phases, however running it earlier or later seems to make no difference.

On failure, I've observed the following:

- The generated .swift file has an import statement, 'import MyProject' which shouldn't be there
- 'No type named [ClassName] in module [MyProject]' OR 'No such module [MyProject]'

SwiftGen version I'm using is 5.2.1
Xcode 9.2, targeting iOS 10.0

SwiftGen from version 5 onwards requires a configuration file, so I've set one up as follows:

```
output_paths: Sources/Generated
storyboards:
  - paths: MyProject/Storyboards/Base.lproj
    templateName: swift4
    output: MyProject/Storyboards/Storyboards.swift
    params:
      ignoreTargetModule: true
```

So far I've looked up documentation and the following issue:
https://github.com/SwiftGen/SwiftGen/issues/273

However the difference is that I'm using a different type of SG installation and my project fails to build (rather than simply not generating any resources)

Cleaning project, build folder and deleting derived data had no effect. I'm assuming that I may have missed something in configuration setup, but I can't see what that would be.

First question on here, so apologies if I missed something, will be happy to edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue with generating `Storyboard` file. Try to modify your config file:

`params:
    ignoreTargetModule: true
    module: <YOUR_PROJECT_NAME>`

Hope it will help.

Comment: Perfect. This actually solved the problem completely. The missing piece was adding the 'module: <YOUR_PROJECT_NAME>' to param list, then it worked like a charm. Thanks so much for contributing the answer

Comment: Thanks @GhostCat for your feedback! Probably yes, I should reread intro again :) Its just not clear what should I do next, should I change my decision (if it possible) or just be more careful next time? :)

Comment: I appreciate the quick and kind comeback. In this case, heho, the OP actually improved the question, so there isnt much to do. So: just be more careful in the future. Remember: when the OP has to edit the question to make it answerable, then the vote is "close as mcve" or something. Voting edit means: you, me, anybody can edit and fix the question ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Hesitant to call this a solution, it's more of a workaround, but the following approach has at least allowed the projects to be built and run.

- Remove the SwiftGen script phase from the 'Dev' target
- Build the project using the main scheme that includes SwiftGen to generate all the necessary objects and constructs
- Switch to Dev scheme and run the project.

The Strings.swift file created by SwiftGen is linked to both targets, so even after running the script in one scheme the resources within that file will be available to both regular and Dev targets.

Hope this helps someone.